# Is $a^nb^mc^k$, $n\neq m$ and $m\neq k$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Is the language, $a^nb^mc^k$, where $n\not=m$ and $m\not=k $ in CFL or not? When the condition is changed to $n\not=m ~\|~ m\not=k $, it can be shown that the language is the union of 2 CFLs. However when $n\not=m$ and $m\not=k $ that approach seems to not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, $L=\{a^nb^mc^k\mid n\neq m,m\neq k\}$ is not context-free.

##### A proof by Ogden's lemma

Assume $L$ is context-free.

Let $p$ be the constant given by [Ogden's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma). Let $s=a^{p+p!}b^pc^{p+p!}\in L$. Let us mark all $b$s in $s$. Ogden's lemma tells that $s=uvwxy$ for some strings $u$, $v$, $w$, $x$, and $y$, such that

- $vx$ has at least one marked position,
- $vwx$ has at most $p$ marked positions, and
- $uv^{i}wx^{i}y\in L$ for all $i\geq0$.

There are several cases.

- If $v$ or $x$ contains different symbols, then $uv^2wx^2y\notin L$, since it contains symbols in the wrong order.
- Otherwise, all symbols in $v$ are the same and all symbols in $x$ are the same.
  Since only $b$s are marked, either $v$ or $x$ must contain $b$.

  - Suppose $v$ contains $b$. Then $v$ only contains $b$s. So $vx$ does not contain $a$. Let $q= \#_b(vx)\le p$. Let $i=\frac{p!}q+1$. Consider $s'=uv^iwx^iy$.

    - $\#_a(s')=\#_a(s)=p+p!$
    - $\#_b(s')=\#_b(s) + \#_b(vx)^{i-1}=p + q(i-1) = p + p!$

    Hence $s'\notin L$..
  - Otherwise, $x$ contains $b$. This case is symmetric to the case above.

So, in all cases, $uv^iwx^iy\not\in L$ for some $i$. This contradicts Ogden's lemma.

Hence, $L$ is not context-free.

##### Two exercises.

**Exercises 1**. Show that $L$ satisfies [the common version of the pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). Hence, $L$ also satisfies [the common version of pumping lemma for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages). However, $L$ does not satisfy [the stronger version of pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#General_version_of_pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

**Exercises 2**. Show that $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid n\neq k,m\neq k\}$ is not context-free.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Can you be sure that there isn't a simpler like pumping lemma based solution? I mean, can you prove that the pumping lemma can't be used here, if that's the case.

Comment: I think the pumping lemma is too weak for such a case. Please check the following reasoning. Consider $a^n b^m c^k$, $n\neq m$, $m\neq k$. If $m>k$, then we can choose $\sigma\in\{1,2\}$ s.t. $\sigma\neq m-k$, and pump as follows: $a^{n+\sigma*i}b^{m+\sigma*i}c^k$. If $m<k$, then we take $\sigma\in\{1,2\}$ s.t. $\sigma\neq k-m$ and simply pump $c$. Thus, the language can be pumped with $p=4$.

Comment: John, your note that $L$ can be pumped at one $y$ position is nice! Thus we do not need two subwords to be pumped synchronously, but the condition $|xy|<p$ in the Regular Pumping Lemma applied to this language $L$ is suspicious. If we take $a^n b^{n+n!} c^{n+n!+1}$, then we are forced to take a subword from $a^n$ to construct the regular pump, which is a problem. EDIT: I see, you mean the general form of the lemma ))

Comment: @user2277550 Good question. Please check exercise 1 in the updated answer.