# The complement of a particular language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, linear-languages

We know that Linear context-free languages are not closed under complement, so I encountered a challenge in finding an example to show the above theorem. I think the complement of $L={a^nb^n}$ is not linear, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Indeed, it is a good challenge to find an example of a linear language, who's complement is not linear. The formulation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar#Negative_cases) if quite indirect.

Comment: Hey, I think I might have found a valid counterexample.
I've added it to my answer, so please have a look :]

Comment: @Knogger Yep. Seems to work. Also the complement of $\{a^nb^nc^n\mid n\ge 0\}$, which is of the same "style" as the language in the question.

Comment: @HendrikJan That's a really nice example.

Maybe a good heuristic is to look out for context-sensitive languages that can be written as
$L = \{x \in L' : \varphi_1(x) \land \varphi_2(x) \land ... \land \varphi_n(x)\}$,
and to hope that the summands of $\overline{L} = \overline{L'} \cup \Big(\bigcup_i \{x \in L : \neg \varphi_i(x)\}\Big)$ turn out to be linear.
Both languages fit that scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement of the language $L = \{a^nb^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ should actually be linear, if I'm not mistaken.
Take some string $x \notin L$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$, since $L \subseteq a^*b^*$ one of three cases must be true:

- $x \notin a^*b^*$, or
- $x = a^nb^m \in a^*b^*$ and $n > m$, or
- $x = a^nb^m \in a^*b^*$ and $n < m$.

So the complement of $L$ (relative to $\Sigma$) can be expressed as
$$\overline{L} = \overline{a^*b^*} \cup \{a^nb^m : n > m\} \cup \{a^nb^m : n < m\}.$$
Now, $\overline{a^*b^*} \in \texttt{REG}$ so $\overline{a^*b^*}$ must be linear.
Using an induction argument over the rules of the linear grammar $G$ with rules
$$S \to aS | aA$$
$$A \to aAb | \varepsilon$$
and start variable $S$, it can be shown that $L(G) = \{a^nb^m : n > m\}$ is linear. Similarly, $\{a^nb^m : n < m\}$ can be generated by a linear grammar with rules
$$S \to Sb | Bb$$
$$B \to aBb | \varepsilon.$$
Since $\overline{L}$ can be written as the union of linear languages, and the linear languages are closed under union, it follows that $\overline{L}$ must be linear as well.

### Counterexample

I think I might've found a valid counterexample.
The language $L = \{a^nb^mc^k : n \neq m \land m \neq k\}$ is well known to be [context-sensitive](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150051/is-anbmck-n-neq-m-and-m-neq-k-context-free).

Observe that
$$\overline{L} = \overline{a^*b^*c^*} \cup \{a^nb^mc^k : n = m\} \cup \{a^nb^mc^k : m = k\}.$$
It can be verified that the linear Grammars
$$S \to Sc | A$$
$$A \to aAb | \varepsilon$$
and
$$S \to aS | A$$
$$A \to bAc | \varepsilon$$
with start variable $S$ generate $\{a^nb^mc^k : n = m\}$ and $\{a^nb^mc^k : m = k\}$ respectively, and that $\overline{a^*b^*c^*} \in \texttt{REG}$.
So $\overline{L}$ is linear whilst $\overline{\overline{L}} = L$ is not, counterexample ↯